# CMAKE - resolving dependencies between libraries in project

Tags: cmake

I am using CMAKE to build a quite large project consisting of many libraries and executables. There is something wrong with how I specify library-library dependencies, and things do not work fully as wanted. Schematically my project looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
lib1/src/CMakeLists.txt
lib2/src/CMakeLists.txt
app/src/CMakeLists.txt
```

I.e. I have two libraries lib1 and lib2 where lib2 depends on lib1 and app depends on both lib1 and lib2. I build libraries using both shared and static linking:

```
add_library(lib1_static STATIC lib1_src)
add_library(lib1_shared SHARED lib1_src)
set_target_properties( lib1_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME lib1)
set_target_properties( lib1_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME lib2)
```

To ensure that the dependies are satisfied I have target_link_libraries() as:

```
#lib2/src/CMakeLists.txt:
target_link_libraries( lib2_shared lib1_shared )
target_link_libraries( lib2_static lib1_static )
```

And for the app:

```
#app/src/CMakeLists.txt
target_link_libraries( app_static lib2_static )   # <- No explicit dependance on lib1
target_link_libraries( app_shared lib2_shared )
```

Now - the problem is that when I make a fresh build it compiles for quite a long time, but when creating the liblib2.so file the error message:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lib1/src/liblib1.so' needed by 'lib2/src/liblib2.so'. Stop.
```

appears. If I then just issue a new make command - things will build successfully. So it seems I have not managed to configure the dependencies correctly? Note that the make output from the first build attempt shows:

```
Linking C shared library liblib1.so
```

So the build itself has suceeded - but it seems like the build will not use the liblib1.s0 file created during this build instance to resolve the lib2 dependencies?

I have tried - and removed again - several varietes of link_directories() and target_depends() without success.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, CMake got confused by usage of

```
set_target_properties( lib1_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME lib1)
```

Try this:

```
target_link_libraries( lib2_shared lib1 )
```

or remove these property settings.

Comment: OK - thanks for answering; as mentioned I eventuelly solved it by upgrading CMake. But I do feel the whole static/shared treatment in my CMakeLists.txt is quite complex - so maybe I can simplify that as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I was using CMake version 2.6 - I upgraded to CMake 2.8 and then it worked for me.